# dplyr mutate_at and ifelse() is not vectorised

Tags: r, dplyr

I am attempting to use `mutate_at` at a subset of columns in my data frame. However, when the function I use is `ifelse`, it does not appear to be vectorizing.

For example, the code below should give the same output as the original input.

```
set.seed(1)
stack_names <- c('a','c','d','e')
stack_df <- data.frame(a = 1:10, b = 11:20, c = 21:30, d = rep(1, 10), e = rnorm(10))

#     a  b  c d          e
# 1   1 11 21 1 -0.6264538
# 2   2 12 22 1  0.1836433
# 3   3 13 23 1 -0.8356286
# 4   4 14 24 1  1.5952808
# 5   5 15 25 1  0.3295078
# 6   6 16 26 1 -0.8204684
# 7   7 17 27 1  0.4874291
# 8   8 18 28 1  0.7383247
# 9   9 19 29 1  0.5757814
# 10 10 20 30 1 -0.3053884

stack_df %>% mutate_at(.vars = vars(one_of(stack_names)), 
                         funs(ifelse(length(unique(.)) == 1, ., .)))
#    a  b  c d          e
# 1  1 11 21 1 -0.6264538
# 2  1 12 21 1 -0.6264538
# 3  1 13 21 1 -0.6264538
# 4  1 14 21 1 -0.6264538
# 5  1 15 21 1 -0.6264538
# 6  1 16 21 1 -0.6264538
# 7  1 17 21 1 -0.6264538
# 8  1 18 21 1 -0.6264538
# 9  1 19 21 1 -0.6264538
# 10 1 20 21 1 -0.6264538
```

Is this a known behavior with `ifelse`? When I try a similar code but use a different function, it works fine.

```
stack_df %>% mutate_at(.vars = vars(one_of(stack_names)), 
                           funs(. + mean(.)))
#       a  b    c d          e
# 1   6.5 11 46.5 2 -0.4942510
# 2   7.5 12 47.5 2  0.3158461
# 3   8.5 13 48.5 2 -0.7034258
# 4   9.5 14 49.5 2  1.7274836
# 5  10.5 15 50.5 2  0.4617106
# 6  11.5 16 51.5 2 -0.6882656
# 7  12.5 17 52.5 2  0.6196318
# 8  13.5 18 53.5 2  0.8705275
# 9  14.5 19 54.5 2  0.7079841
# 10 15.5 20 55.5 2 -0.1731856
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your first parameter to `ifelse` is a logical vector of length 1. You're only going to get one value that way. See

```
ifelse(TRUE, 5:1, 1:5)
# [1] 5    # one 1 value returned, not 5
```

And when you test `length(unique(.)) == 1` are are only going to get one TRUE or FALSE depending on whether or not all the values in the column are the same.

All the parameters to `ifelse` should be the same length. It's unclear what you are really trying to do here so it's not obvious what the solution might be. Seems like you might just want to conditionally perform the mutate or use a `mutate_if` or some sort. Of maybe you just want a regular `if` statement.

```
myfun <- function(x) {
    if (length(unique(x)) == 1) x else x
}
stack_df %>% mutate_at(.vars = vars(one_of(stack_names)), funs(myfun))
```

Comment: ^ bc `length(unique(.))` is not vectorized, it returns a single number (the number of unique values of the column).